# SQLExecDirect doesn't return when deadlocked

Tags: c++, odbc

I have a C++ app calling a stored procedure via SQLExecDirect. If there is a deadlock SQLExecDirect doesn't return until the deadlock is resolved.

I've read in the .net world it can detect deadlocks and throw an exception. Is there any way with C++/ODBC to regain control while deadlocked? I suspect the answer is no, but I'm hoping there's some ODBC feature I haven't found yet.

The only work around I can think of is kicking off another thread to run it and and setting a timeout for the thread to return.

And no, I can't fix the deadlock. This app is running queries or stored procedures from my customer's DBs that they choose. I just don't want it unresponsive for the duration of the deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

If your ODBC provider supports asynchronous execution you could perform the operation that way, ODBC 3.8+ even supports an event-based notification mode over the older 3.0 polling-only. Note that unless using something like SQLServer's MARS your connection will still be deadlocked it just allows the thread to do something else while waiting for an answer.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying check the version of the driver and if > 3.8 I can make my app more responsive but otherwise I'm stuck waiting? Creating a deadlock in MS SQL Management Studio gives this response "Transaction (Process ID n) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim." Was hoping ODBC had some way to tap into that.